# Conversion of integer to char array in C

Tags: c, embedded, type-conversion, misra

I'm developing an ARM embedded application. I'm kind of stuck on a silly problem - I have an array of unsigned 8-bit integers:

```
uint8_t days[42] = { 0 };
```

It's initialized with some data - the initialization algorithm introduces a lot of variables confusing and irrelevant to the problem, so I will not repost it here. I see this array in the debugger variable watch, and I'm certain it is filled with integer values from 0 to 31.

I'd like to take any element of this array, say 15th, and convert it to `char*` so that it can be displayed on my LCD screen. I rewrite it using `sprintf` function:

```
char d[3] = { '0', '0', '0' };
sprintf(d, "%d", days[15]);
```

Just one note: no, I can't use the `stdlib` `itoa()` function, because it does not conform to MISRA-C standards, which I am obliged to follow.

As a result, I only get a binary zero value in my `d` buffer. Any ideas?

Comment: You may be initializing `d` wrongly. If you want all values to be null-terminators, you'll have to use `\0` instead of `0`. This works OK for me, BTW.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never ever use `sprintf` function. Use `snprintf`. You may find that your problems were due to a buffer overflow. You do not need to initialize `d`.

Comment: Why buffer overflow? I never need more than 3 chars, including the terminating character.

Comment: It might be a problem of integer promotion/size rules. Maybe try explicitly casting `days[15]` to an `int`?

Comment: I can't use `int`, it's too large, and pointless - why do I need a 32-bit integer for numbers 0-31?

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski because the `"%d"` format expects an `int` to be passed to `printf`. I'm not saying to store the array as `int`s, I'm saying do `sprintf(d, "%d", (int)days[15]);` - i.e. add the `(int)` cast before `days[15]`.

Comment: Still doesn't help though

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski `printf` always promotes "smaller" arguments to `int`.

Comment: A char can hold values from -128 to 127. -128 requires 5 chars include terminating char to display.`int` is the size which is most effective for the compiler `snprintf( d, sizeof( d ), "%d", (int)day[ 15 ] )` may well generate more effective code than `snprintf( d, sizeof( d ), "%d", day[ 15 ] )`

Comment: He is using MISRA-C so forget about stdio.h. He is also programming an embedded micro-controller system, so forget about stdio.h even more.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - agreed.  Comment was confusing and I removed it. Thanks for pointing out errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MISRA-C compliance, you can certainly not use `sprintf()` or anything else from stdio.h either. You generally want to avoid sprintf like the plague on any embedded system anyhow.

Writing a simple decimal integer to string conversion routine is quite basic stuff... here's my attempt of a MISRA-C (2004 and 2012) compatible version:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void dec_to_str (char* str, uint32_t val, size_t digits);

int main (void)
{
  char str[3u + 1u]; // assuming you want null terminated strings?

  dec_to_str(str, 31u, 3u);

  return 0;
}


void dec_to_str (char* str, uint32_t val, size_t digits)
{
  size_t i=1u;

  for(; i<=digits; i++)
  {
    str[digits-i] = (char)((val % 10u) + '0');
    val/=10u;
  }

  str[i-1u] = '\0'; // assuming you want null terminated strings?
}
```

Note: the uint32_t variable *could* get swapped out for an uint8_t, but then you need to add type casts all over the place, to prevent implicit type promotions, as required by MISRA. The code will then turn really ugly, like this:

```
 str[digits-i] = (char)(uint8_t)((uint8_t)(val % 10u) + '0');
```

The only sane thing to do then, is to split that mess into several lines:

```
uint8_t ch = (uint8_t)(val % 10u);
ch = (uint8_t)(ch + '0');
str[digits-i] = (char)ch;
```

Comment: Fair point, I overlooked that part of MISRA. Yes, I do want null-terminated strings! That works fine, thanks!

Comment: IMO snprintf is a great function to use in embedded systems. (although I can't comment specifically on MISRA)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Depends on what you use it for. If you only want it for simple integer to string conversion like above, we're talking about: hundreds of bytes in wasted stack use, several kb of wasted program memory, slow execution, dangerous function with no type safety, which is not re-entrant. To do the very same job. How exactly is that a great function?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int days[2] = {12,14};
char d[3] = {'0', '0', 0};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    d[0] = days[1] / 10 + 0x30;  // convert 10's digit to ascii
    d[1] = days[1] % 10 + 0x30;  // convert 1's digit to ascii

    // Debugging help
    printf(d);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(d, "%s", d);` this doesn't make sense - you're essentially just copying the string to itself (which may be UB).

Comment: plus, it produces junk results

Comment: @Drew: No.  You are converting an integer in the days array and converting it to a character in the d array.

Comment: @Bruce that's what the first two lines do. The line that supposedly "displays the string" does nothing useful.

Comment: If you changed your third line to `printf("%s", d);`, then I would buy it.  Currently, Line 3 ***is*** just another way of doing lines 1 & 2.  ***sprintf*** does not display anything, it is used to package a buffer with formatting.

Comment: You edited your code - but it is still wrong.  Get rid of the ***sprintf(d, "%s", d);*** line. It is redundant.   Also, do you intend to use same element of `days[]` for each conversion?

Comment: @ryyker: This is apparently an embedded project, inferred by the desire to use as little memory as possible.  The questioner has an LCD screen, implying that he needs to supply the buffer "d" to the LCD driver.  The printf is for my debugging purposes only.

Comment: @ryyker:  This is just an example for the questioner to use as he/she sees fit.

Comment: Still, you have not addressed why you continue to assign values to `d[0], d[1] in the first two lines, then follow up with assignment ***of d to d***, via sprintf().  Do you not see this as redundant (at best)?  The line ***sprintf(d, "%s", d);*** is not needed.

Comment: Mentioned issues aside, this code has at least 10 violations of MISRA-C.

Comment: @ryyker it is not just redundant, it causes undefined behaviour (overlapping input and output)

Comment: @MattMcNabb - agreed.  Thank you.  Op fixed that issue.  Others remain.